# Can you typedef a previously typedef'd statement?

Tags: c, linked-list, typedef

I was assigned to work on some code, but I was given part of it beforehand. It includes this part of code:

```
typedef int ElementType;

struct Node;
typedef struct Node *PtrToNode;
typedef PtrToNode List;
typedef PtrToNode Position;

struct Node {
    ElementType Element;
    Position Next;
    Position Previous;
};
```

The way I understand it is,

1. Instead of writing int we now can write ElementType to define a value as an integer. (Confusion #1)
2. We have defined a structure called Node. (I am unsure why it wasn't defined here).
3. We `typedef` PtrToNode as a pointer of the structure called Node.
4. We `typedef` List as PtrToNote. Which should mean that List is also a pointer to the structure called Node. This pointer is called List. (Confusion #2)
5. Similar to number 4, but this one is called Position.
6. We define how the structure is going to be set up. In this case Element is supposed to be an int, as per our previous definition. Next and Previous are supposed to be pointers of Position? However, if I were to change Position with List, how would this affect the code?

Can someone please explain to me points #1, 2, 4, and 6? Am I understanding the code correctly?

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with your reading of the code. I think the excessive use of type aliases is confusing, but I'm not sure what your confusions are precisely. `struct Node` is forward declared so that the typedefs can be used in its definition. That's pretty common for self-referencing struct types.

Comment: `Confusion #1` - what is confusing about it?

Comment: The line `struct Node;` is unnecessary and can be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Instead of writing int we now can write ElementType to define a value as an integer. (Confusion #1)

This is correct - for example:

```
int a = 50;
```

Is now equivalent to

```
ElementType a = 50;
```

> We have defined a structure called Node. (I am unsure why it wasn't defined here).

This is (forward) *declaring* a structure called Node, not *defining* a structure

> We typedef PtrToNode as a pointer of the structure called Node.

Your understanding here is also correct. Thus the following are equivalent:

```
struct Node *x;
PtrToNode x;
```

> We typedef List as PtrToNote. Which should mean that List is also a pointer to the structure called Node. This pointer is called List. (Confusion #2)

`List` and `PtrToNode` represent the same type - the following examples all do the same thing:

```
struct Node *x;
PtrToNode x;
List x;
```

> Similar to number 4, but this one is called Position.

Correct.

> We define how the structure is going to be set up. In this case Element is supposed to be an int, as per our previous definition. Next and Previous are supposed to be pointers of Position? However, if I were to change Position with List, how would this affect the code?

This is defining the structure `Node`. Replacing `Position` with `List` would have no effect on the code. To two types are compatible.

Comment: Perfect explanation. I didn't know about the forward declaration, or why was it used, and I do now thanks to your explanation. This does help immensely. Thank you.